# Primeira página - Ionic e ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ionic, route

Estou definindo uma página de abertura do aplicativo, onde é exibida uma lista e clicando em um item, o usuário é direcionado para uma página que contém `tabs`.

Como mostrado abaixo:

[image: exemplo]

Cada `tab` deve exibir o conteúdo de uma página html (view). Porém, não estou conseguindo exibir conteúdos dentro dessas `tabs`.

Segue abaixo meu config:

```
$stateProvider
.state('Clientes', {
    url: '/clientes',
    views: {
        'conteudo': {
            templateUrl: "templates/inicio.html",
            controller: 'ClienteController'
        }
    }
})
.state('menu',{
    url: '/menu/:dadosLogin',
    views: {
        'conteudo':{
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
            controller: 'ClienteController'
        }
    }
})
.state('menu.dados', {
    url:'/acessos',
    views:{
        'tab-dados':{
            templateUrl: "templates/tab-dados.html"
        }
    }
});
```

Como posso configurar corretamente os conteúdos dentro dessas `tabs` pelas minhas rotas?

Answer (score 1):

Você já configurou, é só editar os arquivos de template.

Você deve colocar os arquivos de template no diretório `www`.

No seu exemplo, `/minhaApp/www/templates/tab-dados.html`